# Dojo radio button label not showing up

Tags: javascript, radio-button, dojo

I create a radioButton using this code.

```
var slotDurationSettingsRow = dojo.create('tr', null, table);
    dojo.create('td', {innerHTML: 'Slot Dauer'}, slotDurationSettingsRow);
    var durationSettingsTD = dojo.create('td', {align: 'right'}, slotDurationSettingsRow);
    var durationSettingsContainer = dojo.create('div', null, durationSettingsTD);

    var radioOne = new dijit.form.RadioButton({
            label:"RadioButton1",
            value: "tea",
            name: "drink",
        },
        durationSettingsContainer);
```

The button is created but the label attribute doesn't seem to work. please help me find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate label element, like @Layke mentioned.

```
var slotDurationSettingsRow = dojo.create('tr', null, table);

dojo.create('td', {innerHTML: 'Slot Dauer'}, slotDurationSettingsRow);

var durationSettingsTD = dojo.create('td', {align: 'right'}, slotDurationSettingsRow);

var durationSettingsContainer = dojo.create('div', null, durationSettingsTD);

var radioOne = new dijit.form.RadioButton({
    value: "tea",
    name: "drink",
}, durationSettingsContainer);

var label = dojo.create('label', {
    innerHTML: 'RadioButton1',
    for: radioOne.id
}, durationSettingsTD);
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/rYsYe/). Note that the label is attached to the `durationSettingsTD` node.

I would also check [the documentation for](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/RadioButton.html) `dijit/form/RadioButton`, especially the examples. Note that even with the programmatic example, they have a `label` element already in place, but the idea is the same.

Comment: While this is correct, its also incredibly stupid and entirely unique compared to all other dijit form widgets. Dijit has horrendous support for forms in general though..

Answer (score 0):

You can't just create a "label" attribute on the dijit/form/RadioButton widget. You have to actually create your own label and add it to the DOM.

### AMD Style

```
  domConstruct.create("label", {
            for: "Radio_Button_ID",                
            innerHTML: "Label Name"
        }, durationSettingsContainer);
```

### Old pre 1.6< Style

```
  dojo.create("label", {
            for: "Radio_Button_ID",                
            innerHTML: "Label Name"
        }, durationSettingsContainer);
```

Comment: Sorry, if you aren't going to help yourself, I can't help you. "Doesn't work" in your case is impossible to provide any more help. My code is perfectly valid so what you are asking goes beyond the details you have provided.

Comment: I don't know what details do you want. Error console is empty and the label is not there

Comment: I don't think it works because you'd want to put the label under the `durationSettingsTD` node, not `durationSettingsContainer`.